# How do I make a custom unretained class?

Tags: cocoa, class, memory-management

How can I make it so that I can get an unretained instance of a class? You can do this with various Cocoa classes like `NSString` (`[NSString string]`) or `NSArray` (`[NSArray array]`).

How can I do this with my custom class so I can call `[MyClass class]` instead of `[[MyClass alloc]init]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement class method in your class that returns autoreleased object:

```
// Header
+(MyClass*) myClass;

// implementation

+(MyClass*) myClass{
  return [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

Then in your code you'll be able to get your 'unretained' aka autoreleased instance of your custom class:

```
MyClass *myObj = [MyClass myClass];
```